# Mistake in list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

> Problem Solved!

I have two python lists of integers that are randomly generated. I want to find the numbers that are common between the lists.

Using list comprehension, I've come up with this:

```py
new_list = [a for a in list_one for b in list_two if a == b and a not in new_list]
```

However, this returns an empty list. I have a working program using loops that works perfectly:

```py
for a in list_one:
    for b in list_two:
        if a == b and a not in new_list:
            new_list.append(a)
```

What mistakes have I made converting it to a list comprehension?

Comment: Then use the loop that works perfectly. Why do you want to convert it to a list comprehension?

Comment: I don't need a comprehension, but I would like to know what I did wrong anyway. And I would then know for when I need comprehensions in the future.

Comment: You're referencing the new list in RHS before it's even created.

Comment: FYI, I wouldn't want to see code like that. https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#27-comprehensions--generator-expressions

Comment: Ah, thanks @Keith. So I'm guessing that it's impossible to do that in comprehensions. It wasn't giving me the error because I was overwriting the list to compare both programs. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it's hard to tell since there isn't much context here. In general, avoid over-complicating code (someone else may have to maintain it).

Comment: Also, I've never even seen that guide before. I generally go off of PEP 008. And there is nothing in there about comprehensions. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: The Google style guide extends PEP-8 with additional best-practice sections.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks, I'll look through it.

Comment: How about `newlist = [a for a in set(listA+listB)  if a in listA and a in listB]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reference the same list inside of a list comprehension.

Thanks @Keith from the comments of the OP for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple approach with sets,

```
list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list_2 = [5,4,7,7,5,1,2,8,9]

new_list = list(set(list_1) & set(list_2))

print(new_list)
```

It uses the set intersection has a number of benefits compared to a list comprehension:

- The input lists do not need to be sorted (though you can sort them by using [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function.
- The input lists can have different lengths.
- Presence of duplicates is taken care of automatically (sets don't admit those).

Answer (score 0):

I do not think list comprehension is required for intersection of 2 lists.
Anyways you can modify your code to-

```
list_one = [1,3,4,5]
list_two = [1,5]
new_list = []
new_list = [a for a in list_one for b in list_two if a == b and a not in new_list]
print(new_list)
```

you can also do-

```
list_one = [1,3,4,5]
list_two = [1,5]
new_list = []
new_list = [a for a in list_one if a in list_two and a not in new_list]
print(new_list)
```

You can convert it into set and use set1.intersection(set2).

```
list_one = [1,3,4,5]
list_two = [1,5]
new_list = []
new_list = list(set(list_one).intersection(set(list_two)))
print(new_list)
```

Comment: Thanks, but only the last one you wrote worked, and part of the task was to have them in order which didn't work either. Anyway, I've already solved the problem but thanks again!